# Last item of listview should be streched in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a list view and I want the last item expand to the bottom of the screen. In the sample below the list shows its items if content is available. I "You don't have any posts" should appear centered in the lower part of the screen.

```
ListView(
          physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: ...
            content ? content.map(... ) 
            // no content
            : Center(
              child: Text("You don't have any posts")
            )
```

Comment: Check this example, I think it will help you https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41191

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside Listview it's not possible for you to expand but wrap Listview inside Column and add your last widget after Listview and wrap that widget with expanded

**Example:**

```
Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: <Widget>[
            ...List.generate(itemsList.length, (index) {
              return Container(color: Colors.red, child: TextField());
            }),
          ],
        ),
         // Find Last widget to draw before adding to listview and give it here
        Expanded(
            child: Container(color: Colors.yellow, child: TextField())),
      ],
    ),
```

Comment: Thank you. With this solution I got an error that Expanded is outside "A RenderFlex overflowed by 244 pixels on the bottom." when the list is filled with items.

Comment: @MarcS82: make sure your column don't have Listview or Column as parent

Comment: The widget tree is Scaffold -> SafeArea -> PageView -> RefreshIndicator -> Column -> ListView

Comment: try adding SingleChildScrollView above Column